# How do I set the save location of a session in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working with Jupyter Notebook version 4.1.0 and can't seem to manually select the save path.

How does one manually specify where a session is saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch `jupyter notebook` from the command line from inside the desired folder path. This will set the current folder as the start of the directory tree in Jupyter.

If we already have a session running, we can select the option IPython Notebook (.ipynb), from the file menu, under the `Download` as option. After saving the Notebook to a desired path, we can open it using the method described above.